# Why git.exe running when Visual Studio 19 is opened and takes 20 percent CPU?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Why git.exe running when Visual Studio 2019 is opened and takes 20 percent CPU? Can I close it? I tried to end task of git.exe in Task Manager but it returns to work again.

Comment: VS probably started Git to have Git do some kind of background maintenance work. This can include re-compressing the repository to recover wasted disk space. (This work is CPU-intensive and can take hours on very large repositories.)

Comment: I cancelled git in Source Control (now None option is selected), so there is no problem now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's next to impossible to diagnose the reason for this given such a brief description.

The best way to deal with an issue like this is to use the "Report a Problem" feature of VS to create a ticket so that the product engineers can diagnose it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Be sure to use the "record" feature so that suitable diagnostic details are included.

It's also worth checking that you're on the latest version of VS.

Comment: thank you, I just cancelled git in Source Control